# How do you describe the expression of the boy on the left?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, translation

In Chinese, it's called "Xian Qi" which is a mix of dislike, avoid,refusal and disdain. It is usually used by people in the position of power or those who have advantage over others.

[image]

Comment: For real, man? Used on or used by? In English, it's more in the intonation, rather than the words in these situations.

Comment: You are on the wrong site. This is not a Chinese-English translation site. Please read the Tour.

Comment: Now I am confused. I said "used on "because I'm thinking as an author, as I am using this word on someone to describe the expression.

Comment: David, it's not a translation question. I know how to translate it, but I just need to find a better word that match the meaning perfectly.

Comment: David, see this similar question that is well received. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/494354/a-term-for-a-woman-complaining-about-things-begging-in-a-cute-childish-way/494491?noredirect=1#comment1194336_494491

Comment: “X used (the expression) on Y” has X showing the expression when they see Y. So your phrasing claims that it is common for the lower ranks to show “xian qi” when they meet people in authority.

Comment: You could choose or look up synonyms for 'dismissive'. But I'd go with 'disdain/ful', which you suggest.

Comment: I don't think that words like dismissive et alia are age appropriate or context appropriate. They sound like adults being teachy (pedagogical, for sticklers).

Answer (score 1):

The person on the left has a **sneer** (noun) or is **sneering** (verb).

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sneer):

> (verb) 1 : to smile or laugh with facial contortions that express scorn or contempt
>
> (noun) : the act of sneering

Visual depictions of the expression will vary. Usually the nose or brow is engaged in a sneer, with one or both sides of the face drawn upward in a way that shouldn't be mistaken for a smile. The [Body Language Project](http://bodylanguageproject.com/nonverbal-dictionary/body-language-of-the-sneering/), a collection of nonverbal gestures and descriptions, features a mostly symmetrical sneer:

> Sneering happens quickly, often in a split second, when the muscles between the eyes just above the nose contract forcing the skin around the nose to wrinkle and the brows to furrow. Sneers activate the buccinator muscles located on the sides of the face to draw the corners of the lips to twist sideways toward the ears.

[image]

It is also frequently asymmetrical, as the related article for *[nose crinkle](http://bodylanguageproject.com/nonverbal-dictionary/body-language-of-nose-crinkle-nose-turning-or-nose-shrug/)* ("similar to a sneer") shows:

[image]